# How do I save groups and items I've added to the listview from the simulation server?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have 2 listviews in my app. One is for items and other is for groups in which those items are grouped in. So every time I select a group from listview I get displayed different set of items in another. Items are values from the simulation server that are constantly changing.

Now what I am wondering how do I keep them grouped like I've had defined after restarting the app and such?

EDIT: People have been asking me for some code example but I believe I can explain in better via pictures cuz I am not good at explaining code.

[Group_0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOccm.png)

#1 Is where I'd type IP for a server to connect to in this case it is my own pc

#2 Is droplist of simulations currently running at on my pc

#3 Is TreeView of all the items/data groups I can access to from the simulation.

#4 Is list of all the items/data I can pick from the said data groups.

#5 Is a list of my own custom groups.

#6 Is a list of the items/data I added to certain custom group, picked from the simulation. In this case its Group0.

Here is also [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv8B5.png) of Group1

Now what I want to do is save everything I did so I don't have to go through whole process again (connecting to server, picking which simulation, creating new custom groups and picking the items for each of the custom group) each time I exit the app and restart it again.

In other words I want to continue where I've left the app. Connected to the same simulation with same custom groups.

Comment: Could post some code so people could analyse it?

Comment: @SimpleCoder I think this should give you the idea.